# How do I get the audio file working in my create-next-app?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, typescript, next.js, mp3

I have a dashboard component like this that is supposed to play a notification sound when it hits zero on the timer.

Here is the component:

```
    "use client";

import { useEffect, useState } from "react";
import Button from "./button";
import Clock from "./clock";
import Header from "./header";

export default function Dashboard() {
  const [time, setTime] = useState(20); // Initial time in seconds
  const [isRunning, setIsRunning] = useState(false);
  const [gamePhase, setGamePhase] = useState("Not started");

  useEffect(() => {
    let interval: string | number | NodeJS.Timer | undefined;

    if (isRunning) {
      interval = setInterval(() => {
        setTime((prevTime) => prevTime - 1);
      }, 1000);
    }

    if (time === 0) {
      clearInterval(interval);
      playNotificationSound();
      alert("Time to switch!");
      setTimeout(() => {
        changePhase();
      }, 2000);
    }

    return () => {
      clearInterval(interval);
    };
  }, [isRunning, time, gamePhase]);

  function changePhase() {
    if (gamePhase === "In progress") {
      setGamePhase("Break time");
      setTime(20);
    }
    if (gamePhase === "Break time") {
      setGamePhase("In progress");
      setTime(20 * 60);
    }
  }

  function startTimer() {
    setGamePhase("In progress");
    setIsRunning(true);
  }

  function playNotificationSound() {
    if (Notification.permission === "granted") {
      const audio = new Audio("../assets/notification.mp3");
      audio.play();
    } else if (Notification.permission !== "denied") {
      Notification.requestPermission().then((permission) => {
        if (permission === "granted") {
          const audio = new Audio("../assets/notification.mp3");
          audio.play();
        }
      });
    }
  }

  return (
    <main className="flex min-h-screen flex-col items-center justify-evenly p-24">
      <Header
        gamePhase={gamePhase}
        isRunning={isRunning}
        setIsRunning={() => setIsRunning(!isRunning)}
      ></Header>
      <Clock
        gamePhase={gamePhase}
        time={time}
      ></Clock>
      <Button
        gamePhase={gamePhase}
        isRunning={isRunning}
        setGamePhase={setGamePhase}
        setIsRunning={() => setIsRunning(!isRunning)}
        time={time}
        setTime={setTime}
        startTimer={startTimer}
      ></Button>
    </main>
  );
}
```

You can find the audio files in the playNotificationSound() function. The error I'm getting in the browser is as follows.

[image]

The path to the audio files is correct so I'm a bit stumped as to what the issue is and not overly familiar with NextJS.

Any help appreciated!